# Problem with ubuntu 22.04.1 iso file

Tags: iso

I had download ubuntu 22.04 iso file for three times.
In all of them file is corrupted.
What should i do?
What is the problem?

Comment: Use a different computer and/or network? And, of course, prefer torrents that do verify the download and retry for the eventual the corrupt parts until it gets a proper file. The aforementioned suggestions are all about network issues, obviously, but the reason can be the drive you're downloading it to, of course.

Comment: which OS are you using and which tool to download the iso file? Please [edit] into your question

Comment: Thank you very much. I downloaded from another computer and now i have a ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

Download the Ubuntu ISO on the BitTorrent protocol using the link under [Alternative Downloads](https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads).

BitTorrent breaks the file into several smaller pieces and then reassembles the file on your PC. Integrity verification is automatic so the BitTorrent download will have no corruption even if your internet connection is so poor that you can't download the file reliably over HTTP or HTTPS.